# In ASP.NET Core MVC, how to search in a table choosing from a <select> one of the <th> as the filter and keep the option selected after submitting?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc

I checked similar questions here, but I couldn't find any that apply to my problem.

I'm trying some code based on a tutorial in the documentation of ASP.NET Core MVC.

I have a table showing a list of Students from my DB, with two columns: `FirstName` and `LastName`.

A search with an `<input type="text">` using either of the columns works fine. I just need to choose **FirstName** or **LastName** in a `<select>`.

The only problem is that I don't know how to keep showing the chosen option in the `<select>` after submitting the search.

My view and controller follow below:

```
@model IEnumerable<Student>

<h1>Students list</h1>

<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <div>
        <p>
            Filter by
            <select name="chosenFilter">
                <option value="firstName">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)</option>
                <option value="lastName">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)</option>
            </select>

            <input type="text" name="searchString" value="@ViewData["SearchString"]" />

            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </p>
    </div>
</form>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

HomeController > Index:

```
public IActionResult Index(string searchString, string chosenFilter)
{
    IQueryable<Student> students = _context.Student;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        switch (chosenFilter)
        {
            case "firstName":
                students = students.Where(s => s.FirstName.Contains(searchString));
                break;

            case "lastName":
                students = students.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(searchString));
                break;
        }
    }

    ViewData["SearchString"] = searchString;

    return View(students);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it on my own! So I'm here to share. Maybe it's not optimal, but it works for me.

After checking and trying the "select tag helper" documentation...

(see: [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-select-tag-helper))

...I found out how it works and implemented it in my code.

The solution involves listing the select options not in the View, but in a ViewModel. So the select tag helper can use it to generate the html for the select options with the one you want selected depending on the conditions in the controller.

(I actually took the oportunity to also add my list of Students and the searchString to the ViewModel). Follows the new code.

**ViewModel:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestApplication.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class StudentViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }

        public string SearchString { get; set; }

        public string Filter { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> Columns { get; } = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "firstName", Text = "First Name"},
            new SelectListItem { Value = "lastName", Text = "Last Name"},
        };
    }
}
```

**Index action:**

```
public IActionResult Index(string searchString, string chosenFilter)
        {
            var viewModel = new StudentViewModel();

            IQueryable<Student> students = _context.Student;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                switch (chosenFilter)
                {
                    case "firstName":
                        viewModel.Filter = "firstName";
                        students = students.Where(s => s.FirstName.Contains(searchString));
                        break;
                    case "lastName":
                        viewModel.Filter = "lastName";
                        students = students.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(searchString));
                        break;
                }
            }

            viewModel.Students = students;

            //ViewData["SearchString"] = searchString;
            viewModel.SearchString = searchString;

            //return View(student)
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

**View:**

```
    @model TestApplication.Models.ViewModels.StudentViewModel
    
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Students";
    }
    
    <h1>Students list</h1>
    
    <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
        <div>
            <p>
                Filter by <select name="chosenFilter" asp-for="Filter" asp-items="Model.Columns"></select>
    
                <input type="text" name="searchString" value="@Model.SearchString" />
    
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    
                <a asp-action="Index">Full list</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
    
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Students)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```